# create a function for chi_square

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I need to input chi_square function and got stuck because it always shows there is a invalid syntax when run it, wonder how should I write the script? And how do I input "v"?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

data = np.loadtxt("214 ohm.txt", skiprows=1)

xdata = [row[0] for row in data ]#x represents current unit is "V"
ydata = [row[1] for row in data]#y represents voltage unit is "mA"

percision_error_V =  np.array(xdata) * 0.0025 #we are using last digit of reading and multiply by measured voltage
accuracy_error_V = 0.01#we are using DC Vlotage, so use the error it provided online
erry = []

for i in range(len(percision_error_V)):
#to compare percision_error and accuracy_error for Voltage and use the larger one
erry.append(max(percision_error_V[i], accuracy_error_V))

def model_function (x, a, b):
    return a*x + b

p0 = [0 , 0.]#214ohm is measured by ohmeter

p_opt , p_cov = curve_fit ( model_function ,
                           xdata , ydata , p0,
                           erry , True )
print(erry)


a_opt = p_opt[0]
b_opt = p_opt[1]
print(p_cov)
print("diagonal of P-cov is",np.diag(p_cov))

print("a_opt, b_opt is ",a_opt, b_opt)
xhat = np.arange(0, 16, 0.1)

plt.plot(xhat, model_function(xhat, a_opt, b_opt), 'r-', label="model function")

plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata,np.array(erry),linestyle="",marker='s', label="error bar")
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Current (mA)')
plt.xlabel('Voltage(V)')
plt.title("Voltage vs. Current with 220ohm Resistor")
plt.show()

p_sigma = np.sqrt(np.diag(p_cov))
print("p_sigma is" ,p_sigma)
for i in range(len(xdata)):
    sum=sum((ydata[i]-model_function(xdata[i], a_opt, b_opt))
    chi.append(sum)
```

[this is the required function I'm supposed to put on python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KH8CV.png)

Thanks

my code is alright until the equation of chi-square, I wonder how should I fix it?

Comment: Where did 1 came from in 1.append(sum)? Post full code.

Comment: your code is also not indented, which is invalid syntax in python

Comment: Don't name your variables the same as inbuilt functions, `sum` in this case

Comment: `chi_square=sum((ydata[i]-model_function(xdata[i], a_opt, b_opt)-p_sigma)/v` You are missing one `)` in this line. Then, you are using a number `1` as a variable and trying to append to it. That's wrong too

Comment: I just changed from 1 to chi, but still the program doesn't run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an **indentation, 1 missing parenthesis**, and **variable naming** issues so far in this sample of code

FROM

```
for i in range(len(xdata)):
sum=sum((ydata[i]-model_function(xdata[i], a_opt, b_opt))
1.append(sum)
```

TO

```
for i in range(len(xdata)):
    sum=sum((ydata[i]-model_function(xdata[i], a_opt, b_opt)) )
    a.append(sum)
```

Variables cannot be named with numbers. E.g. 1,2,3. They must start with string - a1, alfa, betta, or s_t, _s.

Comment: And after fixing indent, do you think `1.append(sum)` will work?

Comment: sorry I just changed it, but still it reminds me there is an invalid syntax

Comment: I haven't seen other side of the code but in your sample, this is one of the issues.

Comment: @ZengClockwise: `1` is a number. You can't use it as a variable which means you can't append to it

Comment: Yes this is another issue as I commented in your question

Comment: Dude, your code is full of errors) Try to write code on PyCharm and it will show you any syntax error right away.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think its because I just registered, so my vote does not display

Comment: Then I guess you can still mark it as the solution. And happy postings)

Comment: There is a check mark right next to my answer(below downvoting), click it and it will be green. Also, I would suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Don't forget to code in any code editor(I would suggest PyCharm as before mentioned), otherwise, you will always be searching for minor issues.